# Microsoft Teams Chat Messages Order By Query Parameter

Tags: sorting, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, query-string

I tried to retrieve my Ms-Teams Chat(Direct/Group) messages using Ms-Graph API along with the Query Parameter "OrderBy" to sort the response using "createdDateTime", but I faced this error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Query option 'OrderBy' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings.",
        "innerError": {
            "message": "Query option 'OrderBy' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedQueryOptions' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings.",
            "date": "2020-08-20T07:28:36",
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to retrieve my Ms-Teams Chat(Direct/Group) Message Response in an Ascending order with respect to the "createdDateTime"?

Comment: We can repro this issue for orderBy query parameter. We have ask our engineering team for information. We will get back to you in sometime

Comment: OrderBy is not supported for this API